# java my method calls are invalid for some reason that I don't understand

Tags: java, methods, syntax

this may be a big noob mistake but I can't figure out why my IDE doesn't like my method calls.

```
   //main here:
      isLeapYear(-1600);
      isLeapYear(1600);
      isLeapYear(2017);
      isLeapYear(2000);
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    if(year >= 1 && year <= 9999) {
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else if (year % 4 == 0 && year % == !100) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
        //return false if not in year range
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting? are your method calls actually inside the `main` function?

Comment: Please post the whole code. Right know I can only assume: Is your method declared *inside* the `main` method?

Comment: By `year % == !100` presumably you mean `year % 100 != 0`

Answer (score 1):

Your method calls should be inside your `main` method, while the method `isLeapYear` should be outside your main method. Also, the expression, `year % == !100`, in your `else if` clause is syntactically incorrect. It should instead be, `year % 100 != 0`, I believe. Lastly, the last portion of your code (the part marked `//return false if not in year range`) should be outside of the brace underneath it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    isLeapYear(-1600);
    isLeapYear(1600);
    isLeapYear(2017);
    isLeapYear(2000);
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999) {
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 100) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
    }
    // return false if not in year range
    System.out.println("false");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

% operator expecting value at right and ! is acceptable with Boolean and comparable operators. Correct below statement: 
} else if (year % 4 == 0 && `year % == !100`) {

Also remove below 2 statements from main if condition and put out side of main if condition

```
System.out.println("false");
return false;

i.e:
if(year >= 1 && year <= 9999) {
    -------
}
System.out.println("false");
return false;
```